# Excel Table Formula Range Incorrectly Incrementing when Pasting New Data

Tags: excel, range

I'm using Excel 365 on a Mac. My spreadsheet contains a table with three columns: Name, Formula 1, and Formula 2. Name is a constant that gets pasted from a dataset. Formula 1 equals `=ROWS($B$1:$B1)`. Formula 2 equals `=ROW($D1)`

Currently, the table has one row of data with the following values:
`A | 1 | 1`. I then paste in the values, B, C, D, E into the Name column, which adds 4 rows of data to the table.

I'm expecting the second half of the range in Formula 1 to increment by 1. For example, the Second row of data in the table should read: 
`B | 2 | 2`. Instead, the row reads: `B | 6 | 2`. Below are the entire table results:

`A | 1 | 1
B | 6 | 2
C | 3 | 3
D | 4 | 4
E | 5 | 5`

The values in rows 3, 4, and 5 are as expected. However, Formula 1 in row 2 should equal 2, not 6. Looking at the formulas in row 2 of the data, Formula 1 reads `=ROWS($B$1:$B6)` and Formula 2 reads `=ROW($D2)`. Formula 2 correctly incremented the cell reference by 1. However, Formula 1 set the ending row of the range equal to the last row of data.

Is there a reason Excel is setting the ending row of the range in row 2 to be equal to the last row of the table after the data has been pasted? Is there a way to have the range in Formula 1 increment by 1 like the cell reference in Formula 2?

I've used the ROW and ROWS formulas to simplify the question. The actual spreadsheet uses an expanding INDEX MATCH array formula. The results are the same: the ending row reference of the range in the second row of data is equal to the number of rows in the table after pasting in the data. The table then resumes correctly incrementing from row 3.

Please let me know if additional clarification or details are needed. Thank you in advance for any and all help.

**EDIT:**
Thank you for the reply. My apologies. I incorrectly stated Formula 1 as `=$E$1:$E1`. I updated the formulas in the post to match the below screen grab:

[image]

The expected result in cell B3 is `=ROWS($B$1:$B2)`. However, the actual formula being generated when I add rows to the table is `=ROWS($B$1:$B6)`.

I tried the the same thing in Excel 2011 for Mac v14.7.7 and received the expected result, cell B3 equaling `=ROWS($B$1:$B2)`. I tried the formulas on different machines running the same version of Excel, 16.30, and received the same undesired results. I guess the error that I'm experiencing in Excel for Mac v16.30 is a bug (or feature??).

Thank you for the responses.

Comment: I cannot regenerate your problem as when I paste B,C,D,E to the `Name` column, the formula in the other 2 columns are updated correctly, which return `{1,2,3,4,5}` by both formula.

Comment: FWIW I've repo'd this in Excel 365 (Windows).  Does seem like a bug.  If you post your _actual_ formula, I might be able to offer an alternative. Note that repo'ing required pastinge `a` ... `e`, overwriting the one existing entry - this is what your image shows, but is _not_ what the original Q stated. When pasting `b` ... `e` below the table, this issue is not seen

Comment: Did you try to just drag the formula down?